# Strange stdout behavior

Tags: c++, buffer, stdout, std, cout

I'm currently writing a socket program in C++ and I've stumbled across very strange behavior when trying to write to the console (a required task), for some reason.

```
cout << themsg[0] << themsg[1] << endl;
cout << "Phase 3: Supernode sent the message " << themsg[0] << " on dynamic port number " << themsg[1] << endl;
```

themsg[0] is the string "User#2:What's up Dick?"

themsg[1] is the string "39416"

The first line should write "User#2:What's up Dick?" to the console, followed by "39416".

The second line should print "Phase 3: Supernode sent the message User#2:What's up Dick? on dynamic port number 39416"

The console output reads as follows:

```
394162:What's up Dick?
on dynamic port number 39416essage User#2:What's up Dick?
```

I know that themsg[0] and themsg[1] are correct because I wrote their values to a file for verification. It surely has to be some weird stdout issue.

For the first line it appears the 5 characters of themsg[1] overwrite the first five characters of themsg[0]. For the second line, it appears that the first two parameters for cout are ignored, and then there is a message fragment appended.

If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it. I tried using flush() but to no avail. I'm not really sure how the output buffer works, so I'm really lost with this.

Comment: show some code including initialization of `themsg` array.

Comment: the problem was resolved. The string was appended with an /r virtual carriage return. Yikes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have a carriage return symbol, `\r`, at the end of `themsg[0]`. I can reproduce the behavior with the following program on Linux:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "User#2: what's up?\r" << "39416" << std::endl;
}
```

The `\r`, when not followed by `\n`, has the effect of returning the virtual "[carriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)" of the terminal to the beginning of the line, so the next print will overwrite what was already there. You won't see this showing up in a file, though, as the file will just contain both strings including the CR.

Strip off the `\r` before printing.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. Not only did it solve the problem. I learned something too :-). How could a \r be appended to my string? Is this sometimes a result of concatenation?

Comment: @aaronmar: they usually come about when stripping only the `\n` off a string that was read from an internet connection or a Windows file in binary mode. Windows and all text-based internet protocols use `\r\n` to denote end-of-line. C++ text-mode streams may hide that from you, but binary streams don't, and on Unix platforms text and binary are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in your `themes` variable.  I tested your exact setup - and, with proper values, it works correctly.  However I then tested the same setup but appended `\r` to the end of `themsg[1]` and `themsg[2]` - and got exactly your behaviour.  As your string `themsg[1]` is coming from the network, it probably has line ending included - and from a different operating system (e.g. UNIX vs Windows) - this is converted to a carriage return without the line feed - resulting in the behaviour you're seeing.